# Taking the address of a conditional expression

Tags: c, pointers, conditional-operator

I have the following code:

```
struct S {
    int x;
};

#define X(a, s) ((struct S*)(a ? &s : 0))

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    struct S s;
    struct S *t;
    int *x;

    a = 3;
    s.x = 4;

    x = &(X(a, s)->x);
    t = &(X(a, s));
}
```

When I compiled this, I get an error on the last line:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:18:9: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
     t = &(X(a, s));
         ^
```

Why is that "&(X(a, s)->x)" is valid code, but "&(X(a, s))" is not?  Both involve returning the address of a conditional expression.

Comment: Because `X(a, s)` is a number (address, if you wish). And `X(a, s)->x` is an object (field `x` of a struct sitting in that address.). Numbers don't have addresses. Objects do.

Comment: *"Both involve returning the address of a conditional expression"* - the results of the final expression (what is `&` being applied to) in both cases is *not* the same. Expand the macro fully in both locations, then examine the resulting code. What is each line actually doing ?

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `&(X(a, s))`, `&` is applied to `((struct S*)(a, &s : 0))`. The type of that expression is `struct S*`, and it is a value (the value of a pointer to a `struct S`). `&` may not be applied to a value that is not an lvalue.<sup>1</sup>

In `&(X(a, s)->x)`, `&` is applied to `((struct S*)(a, &s : 0))->x`. That expression takes a pointer to a `struct S` and uses it to refer to the member `x`, which is an `int`. It is an lvalue, because it designates the `int` object that is the member `x` (C 2018 6.5.2.3 4 explicitly says the result of `->` is an lvalue). Since it is an lvalue, `&` may be applied to it.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Per C 2018 6.5.3.2 1, the address operator `&` must be applied to a function designator, the result of `[ ]` or unary `*`, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with `register`.